# Elisp: What is the time complexity for basic arithmetic operations using calc functions

Tags: lisp, elisp

This includes addition, subtraction, multiplication, and division.

I'm asked to analyze some algorithms that rely heavily on calling `calc-eval` to work. My teacher does want us to account for the complexity of basic operations when working with large numbers.

How do these arithmetic operations scale as the size of the numbers increase?

Comment: Work through a few examples in base-10 arithmetic with paper and pencil for, say, 1, 2, 5, 10, and 20 digit numbers.  Express the 'cost' in terms of the basic operations on 1-digit numbers.  The computational complexity of basic arithmetical functions is essentially unaffected by the base the numbers are represented in.  And yes, when it comes to multiplication in particular there are 'better' algorithms than the one you learned in school but I bet `calc-eval` doesn't use them.

Comment: good idea! I will see what I find...

Comment: As a side note, why do you think they don't use the more efficient algorithms for multiplication?

Comment: Not so much their difficulty, more that they only really show any material improvement in run time on absolutely humongous problem sizes and if you're dealing with 10k digit numbers you probably shouldn't be using `calc-eval` in the first place.  But I'm really just making an educated guess .